# javascript AMD tags in vim?

Tags: javascript, vim

I'd like to ask for a nice **vim** plugin to display javascript tags (methods, their extensions, etc.) for AMD style.

I have syntax highlights and check, Tagbar, but no actual tags-bar for AMD style javascript. There were similar questions here but I have not found any specifics for asynchronous module definition (AMD) javascript. Another IDE with such feature for Linux will also be welcomed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Tagbar doesn't index JavaScript files all by itself. It uses Ctags or a Ctags-compatible tool under the hood so you can either teach Ctags about the AMD syntax or look for Ctags alternatives that understand the AMD syntax out of the box. See `:help tagbar-extend`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look for ctags alternatives, just hoped someone has already found one